# Explanation about Lapid-Rallis iductive argument (doubling method)

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

I am reading Lapid-Rallis *"On the local factors of representations of classical groups"* and I am completely stuck with the proof of Proposition 3.
In the case $\mathcal V$ is not anisotropic, we take $W$ a non-trivial totally isotropic subspace of $\mathcal V$.

**Question 1:** Can we take any such $W$? In particular, can we take $W$ one-dimensional, thus directly reducing to the base case of the inductive argument?

Using Proposition 2 and the identity $[\Psi^{\mathcal V,\mathcal W}(\omega,s)(f_s^{0,\mathcal V})](e)=d_{\mathcal V;\mathcal W}(\omega,s) \cdot f_s^{0,\mathcal W}$ we arrive at $$Z^\mathcal V(f_s^0,\alpha_0 \otimes \tilde \alpha_0)= d_{\mathcal V;\mathcal W}(\omega,s) Z^\mathcal  W (f_s^{0,\mathcal W},\beta_0 \otimes \tilde \beta_0 ),$$
where $\beta_0$ and $\tilde \beta_0$ are unramified vectors for $\sigma$ and $\tilde \sigma$.
Now using the inductive hypothesis we have $$Z^\mathcal  W (f_s^{0,\mathcal W},\beta_0 \otimes \tilde \beta_0 )=L^\mathcal W (s+\frac12, \sigma\times \omega)/ d^\mathcal W(\omega,s).$$
Finally by the inductive definition of $d^\mathcal V(\omega,s)$ this gives
$$Z^\mathcal V(f_s^0,\alpha_0 \otimes \tilde \alpha_0)=L^\mathcal W (s+\frac12, \sigma \times \omega)/d^\mathcal V(\omega,s).$$
But we want $L^\mathcal V (s+\frac12, \pi \times \omega)$ instead of $L^\mathcal W (s+\frac12, \sigma \times \omega)$.

**Question 2:** Do we have  $L^\mathcal V (s+\frac12, \pi \times \omega)=L^\mathcal W (s+\frac12, \sigma \times \omega)$?

I am almost sure that the answer to Question 2 is no, as this would imply (by the same induction) that $L^\mathcal V (s+\frac12, \pi \times \omega)$ is actually equal to the $L$-function attached to a character or to a representation of $GL_2$. But then what did I miss? How do we get $L^\mathcal V (s+\frac12, \pi \times \omega)$ instead of $L^\mathcal W (s+\frac12, \sigma \times \omega)$?